# Why ajax execute only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

can someone explain me why this execute only first time? It should remove item from minishopping cart, but it works only first time.

This is html section:

```
<div data-itemid="@item.Id" class="item @(i == 0 ? "first" : null) row"> 



                  <div class="remove">
                      <input class="remove-item-cart-btn" type="button" value="Remove" data-itemid="@item.Id" />
                  </div>
```

I have Action in my controler:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveProductFromCart_Catalog(int id)
    {
        var shoppingCartItem = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShoppingCartItems
              .Where(sci => sci.ShoppingCartType == ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart && sci.Id == id)
              .LimitPerStore(_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        _shoppingCartService.DeleteShoppingCartItem(shoppingCartItem, ensureOnlyActiveCheckoutAttributes: true);

        //display notification message and update appropriate blocks
        var updatetopcartsectionhtml = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("ShoppingCart.HeaderQuantity"),
             _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShoppingCartItems
             .Where(sci => sci.ShoppingCartType == ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart)
             .LimitPerStore(_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id)
             .ToList()
             .GetTotalProducts());
        var updateflyoutcartsectionhtml = _shoppingCartSettings.MiniShoppingCartEnabled
            ? this.RenderPartialViewToString("FlyoutShoppingCart", PrepareMiniShoppingCartModel())
            : "";

        return Json(new
        {
            success = true,
            message = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Products.ProductHasBeenAddedToTheCart.Link"), Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart")),
            updatetopcartsectionhtml = updatetopcartsectionhtml,
            updateflyoutcartsectionhtml = updateflyoutcartsectionhtml
        });
    }
```

and this is js function:

```
$(function() {
        $(".mini-shopping-cart").on("click", '.remove-item-cart-btn', function (e)
        {
            alert("test");
            var $this = $(this);

            $.ajax({                   
                url: '@Url.Action("RemoveProductFromCart_Catalog", "ShoppingCart")',
                cache: false,
                data:
                {
                    id: $this.data('itemid')
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $("#flyout-cart").replaceWith(data.updateflyoutcartsectionhtml);
                    jQuery.each($(".cart-qty"), function (i, val) {
                        $(val).text(data.updatetopcartsectionhtml);
                    });
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

I am new in js so dont blame me(a lot).

Thanks in advance!

This is the whole html section:

```
<div id="flyout-cart" class="flyout-cart">
<div class="mini-shopping-cart">
    <div class="count">
        @if (Model.TotalProducts == 0)
        {
            @T("ShoppingCart.Mini.NoItems")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw(string.Format(T("ShoppingCart.Mini.ItemsText").Text, string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart"), string.Format(T("ShoppingCart.Mini.Items").Text, Model.TotalProducts))))
        }
    </div>
    @if (Model.TotalProducts > 0)
    {
        <div class="items">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = Model.Items[i];
                <div data-itemid="@item.Id" class="item @(i == 0 ? "first" : null)">
                    @if (Model.ShowProductImages)
                    {
                        <div class="picture">
                            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = item.ProductSeName })" title="@item.Picture.Title">
                                <img alt="@item.Picture.AlternateText" src="@item.Picture.ImageUrl" title="@item.Picture.Title" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div class="product">
                        <div class="name">
                            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = item.ProductSeName })">@item.ProductName</a>
                        </div>
                        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.AttributeInfo))
                        {
                            <div class="attributes">
                                @Html.Raw(item.AttributeInfo)
                            </div>
                        }
                        <div class="price">@T("ShoppingCart.Mini.UnitPrice"): <span>@item.UnitPrice</span></div>
                        <div class="quantity">@T("ShoppingCart.Mini.Quantity"): <span>@item.Quantity</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="remove">
                        <input class="remove-item-cart-btn" type="button" value="Remove" data-itemid="@item.Id" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="totals">@T("ShoppingCart.Totals.SubTotal"): <strong>@Model.SubTotal</strong></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            @if (Model.DisplayShoppingCartButton)
            {
                <input type="button" value="@T("ShoppingCart.Mini.ViewCart")" class="button-1 cart-button" onclick="setLocation('@(Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart"))')" />

            }
            @if (Model.DisplayCheckoutButton)
            {
                var checkoutUrl = "";
                if (Model.AnonymousCheckoutAllowed && Model.CurrentCustomerIsGuest)
                {
                    checkoutUrl = Url.RouteUrl("LoginCheckoutAsGuest", new { returnUrl = Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart") });
                }
                else
                {
                    checkoutUrl = Url.RouteUrl("Checkout");
                }
                <input type="button" value="@T("Checkout.Button")" class="button-1 checkout-button" onclick="setLocation('@checkoutUrl')" />
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it only works the first time?

Comment: If i have 5 items in shopping cart it only works for one button and stop working for others. When i refresh page it works for first time and then stop working on others items.

Comment: please post the html fragment starting from #flyout-cart

Comment: When you do this `$("#flyout-cart").replaceWith(data.updateflyoutcartsectionhtml);`, are you replacing the `$(".mini-shopping-cart")` elements with new HTML?  If so, you are wiping out the event handlers on those buttons.

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing the html. I suspect @jfriend00 is right. The fact your not deleting the button and its associated elements in the `success` callback (meaning you could click the same button and delete an item which has already been deleted) suggests that your actually completely replacing the html which means it would not work. `$(".mini-shopping-cart")` needs to exist when the page is first generated and remain in place.

Comment: I posted the whole html view in my question.

Comment: If that _whole html view_ you have included is the partial view you replace with `$("#flyout-cart").replaceWith(data.updateflyoutcartsectionhtml);` then you problem is as described in the previous comments. But there is no need to return a partial view to replace the existing html. In the success callback, just remove those elements of the DOM associated with the button you just clicked.

Comment: Either that or you need a containing elements (say) `<div id="container">` around the `<div id="flyout-cart" class="flyout-cart">` element and then its `$('#container').on("click", '.remove-item-cart-btn', function (e) { ... });` - i.e the enclosing div exists when the page is first rendered and is not replaced.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you a lot. It worked now!
Thank you guys. :)

Comment: Note you should be using the first option I noted (the 2nd will work but its just unnecessary extra overhead to send back the partial and replace it) - your would just need to send back an additional value for the subtotal so you can update the `<div class="totals">` text